# Using Sitecore Forms with Dynamics 365

Tags: wffm, sitecore-forms, dynamics-crm-module

I have a client using Sitecore 9.0.1 with a requirement to create or update contact information in `Dynamics 365` following a form submission. What is the correct way to go about this in the new Sitecore 9 world?

As best I can tell, my main options are:

- `Sitecore Forms`, which is new, intuitive UI, but limited in submit actions. We are currently using Sitecore Forms in a couple of areas of the site already for basic data capture.
- `WFFM`, which is an ageing behemoth with lots of features but an older approach and not as appealing design. It has submit actions for a wide range of behaviors. It does also have some `CRM` connectors that have been built for previous versions of Sitecore.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go for Sitecore Forms. WFFM is no longer included in 9.1 so that is a dead end...

You will need to create your own submit actions (in both options btw) if you want it on this version..  If you can wait just a little longer until the actual release of Sitecore 9.1 (announced for November) you will get an ootb data prefill framework in Sitecore Forms but that will only get you read functionality. You will still need to write your own "writes"..

You can check https://github.com/bartverdonck/Sitecore-Forms-Extensions and https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/digital_marketing/sitecore_forms/setting_up_and_configuring/walkthrough_creating_a_custom_submit_action_that_updates_contact_details as a guidance on how to implement your save-requirements.

Comment: I would maybe add similar submit action as mentioned in official documentation https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/digital_marketing/sitecore_forms/setting_up_and_configuring/walkthrough_creating_a_custom_submit_action_that_updates_contact_details to update contacts

Comment: I will look into these, thanks for the quick responses both.

Comment: @Gatogordo The 2nd link you referenced seems to have changed by now.
This must be the correct one:
https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/91/sitecore-experience-manager/walkthrough--creating-a-custom-submit-action-that-updates-contact-details.html PS Sorry for posting an answer instead of adding a comment, but StackExchange doesn't allow me to comment.

Answer (score 3):

What Gert said is 100% valid.

If you don't have to save in dynamics CRM in real time you can use Dynamics CRM Connect Module.

After you create contacts in XDB you can use Dynamics CRM Connector to syncronize from xDB to Dynamics CRM.

Dynamics CRM Connector has pipeline batches to sync

1. XDB Contacts -----> CRM Contacts
2. CRM Contacts -----> XDB Contacts

You can find the module at : https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Dynamics_CRM_Connect/2x/Sitecore_Connect_for_Microsoft_Dynamics_365_for_Sales_201.aspx

After you install it you can have scheduler task which will run Pipeline batches to sync XDB Contacts to CRM.

You can set up how often to run sync, you can add some filters without writing any custom code.

[image]